Camera world angle
I want to know the camera angle based on world coordinates. I use rotation to convert radian to Degrees. But the rotation is Euler angles which uses local coordination.
Is there a way or property to get the Angle based on world coordinates instead of calculating it myself?

It is not clear what you mean by "angle". Is camera.getWorldDirection( vector3 ) or camera.getWorldQuaternion( quaternion ) what you want?

@WestLangley Thanks for your answer. I want to know x, y, z angle based on world coordination. The camera.rotation is Euler angle that uses local coordination.
